# Codificando e decodificando senhas com rotação de caracteres

Tags: java, senhas

Tenho um banco de dados com um campo senha, que tem uma espécie de "criptografia".

Analisando a lógica: criei usuários no sistema e coloquei a senha: 123. Quando fui consultar a senha no banco ela estava: 032.

Se formos para um raciocínio lógico, quando eu coloquei 1, ele gerou 0(um valor abaixo); quando coloquei 2, gerou 3(um valor a cima) e depois o 3, gerou 2(um valor abaixo).

Outros exemplos:

```
SENHA                        RESULTADO NO BANCO
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz   'cbedgfihkjmlonqpsrutwvyx{
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ   @CBEDGFIHKJMLONQPSRUTWVYX[
0123456789                   1032547698
```

(lendo a senha ele vai substituindo a cada posição um valor a cima e outro abaixo).

Como posso gerar essa lógica em Java?

Comment: Amigo talvez isso lhe ajude a editar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, muito Obrigado. Mas pelo que coloquei lá em cima deu pra entender que não possuo o código, quero desenvolve-lo a partir da lógica reportada.

Comment: Segue a solução, se reabrirem posto como resposta. http://ideone.com/lIUpWe Notar que você editou com o exemplo do "master" mas se for realmente alternado, o resultado é outro. Crie usuários com senhas mais longas, como 333333, dddddd, etc para ver se procede a lógica.

Comment: Oi Bacco, criei essas senhas:
senha crianda     : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 - resultado no banco: 'cbedgfihkjmlonqpsrutwvyx{
Senha Criada   : ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 - resultado no Banco: @CBEDGFIHKJMLONQPSRUTWVYX[
Senha Criada   : 0123456789
 - Resultado no Banco: 1032547698

Comment: é, parece ok. Chegou a ver o link que eu postei? pra decidir o primeiro caractere se é "pra cima" ou "pra baixo" basta inverter o j ( int j=1 para int j=-1 ) **http://ideone.com/lIUpWe**

Comment: agora, se esses exemplos estão certos, pode ser que o "sentido" varie conforme o ID ser par ou ímpar, ou qq outra idéia doida, pois em cada caso a "rotação" está pra um lado.

Comment: vi sim Bacco, mas analisando seu código ele faz uma posição meio que fixo, pq quando fiz o teste no código digitando: master ele não me retornou, exemplo o "a" como " ' ". Ele me retorna esse valor se o "a" for na primeira posição, entendeu?

Comment: entendi perfeitamente, o problema é que se é 1 pra baixo e 1 pra cima, ou é lb, ou é n'  o começo. depende da posição. Pode ser que a lógica use algo a mais que você não considerou, como a paridade do caractere anterior, ou algum outro componente que não fique só no 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 - isso voce vai perceber se testar com aaabbbbccccc por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado cara, vc esta me ajudando muito. Mas pelo que estou vendo, ele não segue essa lógica.

Comment: Esse é o perigo de fazer a pergunta baseado numa impressão inicial. O melhor a fazer seria testar vários exemplos diferentes, e fazer uma tabela com os resultados, não apenas sequencias parecidas. Quanto mais amostras, mais chance de entender. Pode até ser que o campo Nome influencie na senha, quem sabe. So testando. Cadastrar 3 vezes a mesma senha e ver se ficam iguais é outro teste relevante.

Comment: mas eu tenho essas informações no Banco dele, e vejo que os valores não se intercalam(1 para cima e outro para baixo) por isso a ajuda para poder gerar um código que faça a mesma coisa. Pelo que estou vendo, é como se fosse substituição, ex: "a" = "'", etc...e como se seguisse a tabela ascii, onde antes do "a" vem "'" e antes do "A" vem "@"

Comment: Vi outra senha aqui:
Senha Criptografada    : O@U@M3105 - 
Eu traduzir pela tabela: NATAL2014 - 
Gerado pelo seu        : O@U@M1105 - 
Viu que deve ser algo de substituição?

Comment: Só para responder ao seu último comentário, antes da edição do @Bacco sua pergunta era bem confusa, por isto independente de ter ou não código, você deve entender que o que é óbvio para você dependendo da maneira que você escreve pode ser que não seja claro para os demais. Nota: Quando você responder a alguém especifico use `@NomeDoUsuario`, pois se não não aparece nada na "INBOX". Boa noite.

Answer (score 5):

Conforme mencionei nos comentários, para rotacionar os caracteres para "cima" e para "baixo" alternadamente, basta este código:

```
    String s = "ABCDEmasterbbbbbbb123";
    int j = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        c += j;
        j = -j;
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lIUpWe)**.

Conforme você notou, a alternância do seu exemplo às vezes começa com -1, e as vezes com +1. Para fazer isto no código, basta alterar a linha `int j = -1;` aplicando à logica que determina o "lado" da alternância.

Com os dados da pergunta, em princípio a solução é esta. O que falta é encontrar qual é o critério para determinar o `j` inicial, mas é mero ajuste no código. Por exemplo, pode ser o fato do ID ser par ou não, ou depender de outro campo da tabela. Aí já depende da análise dos dados.